# Funky pdfscreen margins

Tags: margins, pdfscreen

You can set the margins on pdfscreen to `0pt`, but when the vertical size is < 1.2in there remains a gap at the top of the page. `\textheight` has the correct value, and it is possible to write all the way to the top using `\vspace*` or `\raisebox`, but the values needed change depending on the size of the page.  Is this fixable?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xspace,xcolor}
\usepackage[screen,nopanel]{pdfscreen}

\margins{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\screensize{1in}{4in}
\backgroundcolor{lightgray}% to make margins visible

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-.3in}
\hfil\rule{0.5pt}{\textheight}
\newpage
\hfil\raisebox{0pt}[.835in][0pt]{\rule{0.5pt}{\textheight}}
\end{document}
```

Also, note that \background color fills the whole page.  It uses the following
bit of code in the sty file, but I can't figure out how it works.

```
\newcommand{\@Overlay}{%
  \ifx\@Overlay@Hook\@empty
  \else
    \bgroup
      \@tempdima=1in
      \@tempcnta=\@tempdima
      \@tempcntb=-\@tempdima
      \advance\@tempcntb\paperheight
      \global\setbox\@cclv\vbox{%
      \vbox{\let\protect\relax%
        \unitlength=1sp%
        \pictur@(0,0)(\@tempcnta,\@tempcntb)%
          \@Overlay@Hook%
        \endpicture}%
        \box\@cclv%
      }%
    \egroup
  \fi
}
\PDFSout{\@Overlay}
```